# IIS Express doesn't serves images on ASP.NET Web Forms app, image location serves 404

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis-express

I am creating an ASP.NET web form application from Visual Studio 2017.
I have created :

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="~\\image\\ap.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="~\image\ap.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="image/ap.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I ran the webapp from Visual Studio, but it only serves broken image links. While I copied the image location and pasted it to my browser : `http://localhost:1905/~//image//ap.jpeg` or `http://localhost:1905/~/image/ap.jpeg` or `http://localhost:1905/image/ap.jpeg`, it all complained 
`HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

The image should be there, I have created the image folder just on the root of the webapp.

Why is this and how to remedy this ?

Answer (score 0):

Links with ~ are for server controls and the single-slash should be forward

```
<img src="~/image/ap.jpeg" />
```

but they'll only work with runat server

```
// html tag with runat server.
<img runat="server" src="~/image/ap.jpeg" />

// server control.
<asp:Image runat="server"></asp:Image>
```

To make sure the html tag works (should work), add a slash to the beginning to signify the root

```
<img src="/image/ap.jpeg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simply caused by the wrong extension. It should be .jpg not .jpeg, which was totally my stupid fault here.

`<img src="image/ap.jpg" />` works.

Thanks for the other responses.